# react-http-request does not change loading state after second request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am now using react-http-request in my React.js component to send request and process the response. The URL parameter passed is relevant to the component state such that when the state changes, the component will be re-rendered and change the component display.

This works on the first request. However, I found that the component does not return a {load: true} after the second request, and I wonder how to solve this.

I tried to call the onRequest method and set the loading state for the component, but I cannot change the loading state after the request is finished (as render function cannot change the state).

react-http-request: https://github.com/mbasso/react-http-request

My Code is like below:

```js
var FilmList = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            queryType: this.props.queryType
        }
    },
    // ... details emitted.
    render: function(){
        return (<Request
            url={config.url.api + "/" + this.state.queryType}
            method="get"
            accept="application/json"
            query={{ several parameter }}
        >
        {
            ({error, result, loading}) => {
                if (loading || error) {
                    return <Loading />
                }
                else {
                    // process the result here.
                }
            }
        }
        </Request>)
    }
```

Comment: any reason why you have to use react-http-request? the project seems very small, why not use fetch or request.js instead?

Comment: @ospfranco I am quite new to react.js, and react-http-request is the one I chose for the first time. I read request.js and I found that this also requires me to re-render the component after the request changes, and react-http-request has provided profound implementation for the loading/request state.

Comment: I actually feel react-http-request is breaking a good encapsulation of the UI and the state of your application, I will provide an answer using `fetch` maybe it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I read the source code of the react-http-request, and found that there is a weakness that after accepting and sending the second request, the component failed to update the state of "loading" returns.

```
// starts from Line 49
value: function componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (JSON.stringify(this.props) === JSON.stringify(nextProps)) {
    return;
  }

  this.request.abort();
  this.performRequest(nextProps);
}
```

Manually changed the state of loading here can help reset the loading after each request received.

I changed the source code of this lib, and sent the pull request to the repo. It's now merged into master and ejected a new release.

See: https://github.com/mbasso/react-http-request/pull/3

Thus, this problem can be solved by keeping the lib update to the release (currently it is 1.0.3).

Answer (score 2):

So, my initial recommendation would be that you use some state management library (redux, mobx, etc) but it is not necessary to get a working example of your code, so:

```
import fetch from 'whatwg-fetch'; // gives compatibility with older browsers

var FilmList = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            queryType: this.props.queryType,
            content: null
        }
    },

    componentWillMount: function() {
      this.fetchContent();
    },

    fetchContent: function() {
        const uri = config.url.api + "/" + this.state.queryType;
        // You can use w/e you want here (request.js, etc), but fetch is the latest standard in the js world
        fetch(uri, {
          method: 'GET',
          // More properties as you see fit 
        })
        .then(response => response.json()) // might need to do this ;)
        .then(response => {
          this.setState({
            content: response
          })
        })

    },

    // ...

    render: function(){
        const content = this.state.content? (
          // render your content based on this.state.content
        ): (
          <Loading />
        )

        return content;
    }
});
```

Haven't tested this code, but there are some nice benefits to it:

- The http request is not dependant on React, which should (in theory) be for UI components.
- The fetching mechanism is decoupled, and can be re-used at any point in the component lifecycle
- In my opinion easier to read, divided into smaller logical chunks

I would recommend reading the [React Component Lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html).

Comment: I tried to re-write the original lib code of react-http-request, and I found that this library does not set the loading state to `true` when the componentWillReceiveProps function is called. After I re-added this argument, the loading state will be rendered.

Comment: I have read React.Component document when I learn the React, and I do not quite understand your opinion about react-http-request. I read the code of react-http-request, I think its state control is quite feasible for react.js. Hoping to see your further comment on this!

Comment: The problem I see with react-http-request is that you are directly intertwining your UI declaration with a HTTP request, so you got your view (`render` function) directly performing an HTTP request, which in turns modifies the state of your application (in your case implicitly) and returns a new UI, this completely breaks the idea of react: your UI should be stateless function which given the same inputs produces the same outputs. It might work but clearly breaks the o-so-nice ideals react strives for. p.s. if you find this useful don't forget to upvote :)

Comment: I think otherwise. I read the source code of react-http-request, it send HTTP request in the component, in render change the state of application implicitly, indeed. However, in your case, what is the difference if we view this from the parent component? Is it still sending the HTTP request in the render function of the parent component? Because I think the life cycle of the child component and the parent is not the same.

Comment: You are right, parent lifecycle and children lifecycle are not the same! The difference is: the http request is not being sent from the `render` method, which should be responsible for `rendering` only ;), it makes things clearer, nicely decoupled, think of it this way: if your render method fails, then your http call fails, and vice versa, the whole thing falls apart. with a de-coupled approach your http call can fail and yet your UI will continue to work, and vice versa, if your UI is not correct it won't affect your http call.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Now I am much clearer about this! For this project, I solved the case by changing the source code (also sent PR as posted), in the later projects, I will try otherwise. Thanks again!